# Angular 2 component initialize multiple time

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am working on an **Ionic 2** project and facing to bellow issue. When user logout from application redirects to **Login** page using **navController** like bellow.

```
this.navController.setRoot(LoginPage);
```

When user login next time to application redirect to **Inventory** Page.

```
this.navController.setRoot(InventoryPage);
```

Problem is **InventoryPage** component ***initialize twice*** when user login again. While I'm debugging found Progress bar component also initialize with it(**I'm using a progress bar component inside the InventoryPage.html**)

```
<progress-bar [value]="progress | async"></progress-bar>
```

inside this progress bar component I'm using **ngZone.run()** function to detect progress value changes.

```
 @Input()
    set value(progress: number) {
      this.ngZone.run(() =>  {
        if (progress < this.defaultValue) {
         this.currentProgress = this.defaultValue;
         this.updateProgress(true);

        } else if (progress > this.defaultValue && progress < this.maxProgress) {
         this.currentProgress = progress;
         this.updateProgress(true);
        } else if (progress === this.maxProgress) {
         this.currentProgress = this.maxProgress;
         this.hideProgressbar();
        }
      });
   }

  private updateProgress(visible: boolean) : void {
   this.isVisible = visible;
   this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
  }

  private hideProgressbar() {
   setTimeout(() => {
    this.updateProgress(false);
   }, 2500)
  }
```

This issue is not occur if comment out this ngZone.run() function. has anyone face to this problem ?

Comment: I guess you still holding reference to InventoryPage. Make sure you dismiss all of your references. Please check if InventoryPage onDestroy method is called when you navigate out to loginPage

Comment: The ngOnDestroy method is not invoking. Do I need to call it manually when navigate?

Comment: No, Angular should call it when the instance of your component is destroyed. You should check your code and check where you hold 'this' and not releasing. It is probably due to an open subscription of some kind you have in your component or an async function that uses your component instance..

Comment: But my point is how it's related to ngZone() function. After comment out that function application working without any issues.

Comment: Can you share the code that is inside you ngZone?

Comment: Gili, I have updated the question.

Comment: hideProgressbar() is an async function.. You have a setTimeout that prevent from your component from been destroyed. I suggest you toy change the setTimeout function into an observable and then you can easily unsubscribe from it : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/timer.md. One more thing, setTimeout causes your application change detector to kick in.. uselessly thats not what you want..